# Simple (preferably OO) method to make parallel/concurrent API calls using Scala?

Tags: scala

My application now requires me to make several thousand API calls every minute to check for updates. I've never done anything like this before and am very lost / struggling to get started. I've looked up all sorts of frameworks/libraries that might be able to help. I've looked at one of the most recommended HTTP4S but am utterly confused since I've never done any functional programming and I don't have time right now to learn this. I don't understand any of the examples and I'm very hesitant to use what I can't understand. I've also looked at an Akka library, STTP, and play ws but again pretty confused by the examples.

I guess I'm just asking for some help, maybe an example using a simple library to make parallel API calls.

**EDIT** Adding some semi-Pseudo Code Below of what I'm trying to do

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer 

object TestObject {

  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val customers: ListBuffer[Customer] = DBSingleton.getCustomers

    for(customer <- customers) {
      val response = doApiCall(customer)
      if(response == "Yes"){
        doTheOtherThingForThisCustomer(customer)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But instead of waiting for each response from the API on doApiCall, I'd like to call it for each customer at the same time.

Comment: Give us as much code as you can. We have no clue what you're doing with these API calls, or what sorts of parameters they need. Pretend like you have a function called doApiCalls that works, and write up the rest of your code with that, so we have a better idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `doTheOtherThing()` doesn't return anything meaningful, so you could just do this:

```
import concurrent.Future

...
for (customer <- customers) Future {
  val response = doApiCall(customer)
  if(response == "Yes"){
    doTheOtherThingForThisCustomer(customer)
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tested this it looks like it should work. Thank you.

Comment: I got you jwvh. My Apologies. Thank you for the help. I'll still await a day or so for other answers before declaring yours as accepted.

Comment: Agreed. A wise choice.